# Why navigator not working in onSubmitted of TextField in flutter?

Tags: flutter

This is my code:

```
AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SearchScreen(
                  query: _query,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        title: Container(
          height: 40,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: kSecondaryColor.withOpacity(0.1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
          child: TextField(
            onSubmitted: (value) {
              print('HHi');
              _query.searchBy = value;
              Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/ads');
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SearchScreen(
                    query: _query,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: lang == 'en' ? 11 : 5),
                hintText: 'Search'.tr()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Here I tried everything to navigate and tried the pushNamed way and normal push way but nothing happened, the print is works but Navigator is not works, and I tried wrap TextField in Builder and still not working, even it's not shows any errors, nothing happening, The paradox is it's works when I click on button in the same widget and the same AppBar.

I need push into search result screen after click on enter on keyboard, I hope if there another way instead of onSubmitted.

> flutter version 1.22

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but did you check the last updated about Navigator 2.0?

Comment: @OsaXma nope, where can I check?

Comment: I search about it, what the difference in writing the code?

Answer (score 0):

Need to pressed enter key of your keyboard. and focus out from you text field.

[Check Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35435)